# How to update the screen in network enable application in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Suppose this is my first screen

1. **a**. it contains BasicEditField to enter url.

   **b**.  In that screen, on the makeMenu function, we add a menu item "get"
          and on clicking get, the requested webpage is retrived. The web page contains JSON object and i parse the JSON object and i get the strings like 1.roll_no 2.name 3.marks.

   Now my qyestion is on clicking the **get Menuitem**, how can i display this strings(I mean parse JSON Object) in anew screen instead of the original screen where i had entered the url. Plz help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Runnable` of your `MenuItem` just have it push a new screen that either has a constructor that you feed the Strings into, or expose some methods on your screen that set the Strings.

If you don't know how to parse JSON (and are using an OS other than 6), check out org.json.me. If you're using 6, the JSON classes are already included.